# How can I smooth an uneven concrete floor?

Tags: concrete, slab, self-leveling-concrete

I have had a extension built at the back of my house. It is almost complete now. I had a 6 ft. 6 in. patio door at the back of the house, and the builders left it till last to remove. This will leave my kitchen to be open plan into the extension. When they removed the door, they found that the floor was a different level. As a fix, the builders, working by hand, have put more concrete down in strips. I wanted to put a quality laminated floor down, but the strips have made the floor uneven. Would a floor leveler product be appropriate in this application?

Comment: How high and wide are the gaps?

Comment: Like all leveling problems, you've got two choices: Build it up or Tear it down. That is, apply more stuff, or rent a grinder and grind it down.

Comment: Can you specify the height difference?

Answer (score 1):

Self leveling cement is exactly the right solution.  It's basically a very wet cement that will flow everywhere.  Many professional floor installers use just this to prepare a floor.